# Android App Incompatible on google play only for certain devices

Tags: android, google-play

This is the link to my google app
       [QuizByte](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brainistic.quizbyte)

The app was developed for android api level 13 and above. after publishing some of the phones (Samsung Duos(GT-S7262) )which should be compatible cant see the app in google play. sending a direct link to the phone to email and checking shows that 'this device is no compatible'.

I searched and tries everything I can 
Tried adding  and removed unused permissions but still no luck.

And when I upload it into google play it shows lots of samsung and sony(which should be compatible) in the incompatible-device list.

Thank you.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name = "android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false" />
```

.

Compatible devices were increased (~+500) when I added  in manifest
But it still shows not compatible with sony and samsung models

Comment: The GT-S7262 doesn't have GPS, so it may balk at requiring "fine location." Why would you need that for a quiz app anyway? Why would you need location *at all*?

Comment: @323go a lot of ad platforms present localized ads based on the user's location, I'm guessing this is the case for this app.

Comment: Not sure why they'd need ads when they have IAP.

Comment: @32go GPS was added for easy signup(location & country) to be automatically filled.- Not for ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it working after Changing the minimun SDk Level to 9. Now its showing in the samsung sony devices,

Dont know the exact reson though.Thought that Someone with a similar problem may try this